# What is the alternative for Juggernaut in Rails 3.0.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, websocket, juggernaut

I have learnt that Juggernaut is not supported on Rails 3.0.7.

Are there any other options around ?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Juggernaut yet, but until it supports modern Rails, 
you could try something like this: https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-ruby.